# How to get real time auto generated key for the purpose of update current user data in real time database?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image]In this image auto generated key i want to access but not accessing Any one i can help me Thanks in advance

I am trying to get auto generated key to update real time data but failed

Comment: When you put a new value, the response status usually contains the new documentID

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.